# Song Information Retrieval

Tags: c#, audio, mci

I am trying to retrieve details from an .mp3 file in C# for an audio player.

Code snip:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]

private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

public static void Close()
{
    _command = "close MediaFile";
    mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    isOpen = false;
}

public static void Open(string sFileName)
{
    _command = "open \"" + sFileName + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile";
    mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    isOpen = true;
}

public static void Play(bool loop)
{
    if (isOpen)
    {
        _command = "play MediaFile";
        if (loop)
            _command += " REPEAT";
        mciSendString(_command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- How would I set the volume of the song?
- How would I get the bit rate/sample rate of the song?

I would prefer using MCI or NAudio since I am aware of their reliability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set volume:

```
string command = "setaudio MediaFile volume to " + volume.ToString();
error = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

where volume is an int between 0 and 1000

There is a whole list of mci command strings on in the multimedia reference on msdn at:
[set command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There is also a good example project on CodeProject that does most of the tings you are trying to do at:

[Simple MCI Player](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63094/Simple-MCI-Player)

HTH

Paul